# How to listen to the change in dir or file?

Tags: c, inotify

I have code to listen change in directory, 
When I run it writes nothing in the file neither shows in out out on terminal.

Can any one please help me out to listen the changes take place in particular text file? I want to store timestamp and what change took place.

Code is:

```
/*This is the sample program to notify us for the file creation and file deletion takes place in “/tmp” directory*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/inotify.h>

#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) )
#define EVENT_BUF_LEN     ( 1024 * ( EVENT_SIZE + 16 ) )

int main( )
{
  int length, i = 0;
  int fd;
  int wd;
  char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];
  char str[] = "This is tutorialspoint.com";
  FILE* fp=NULL;;
  fp=fopen("f1.txt","rw+");

  /*creating the INOTIFY instance*/
  fd = inotify_init();

  /*checking for error*/
  if ( fd < 0 ) {
    perror( "inotify_init" );
  }

  /*adding the “/tmp” directory into watch list. Here, the suggestion is to validate the existence of the directory before adding into monitoring list.*/
  wd = inotify_add_watch( fd, "/tmp", IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE );

  /*read to determine the event change happens on “/tmp” directory. Actually this read blocks until the change event occurs*/ 

  length = read(fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN ); 

  /*checking for error*/
  if ( length < 0 ) {
    perror( "read" );
  }  

  /*actually read return the list of change events happens. Here, read the change event one by one and process it accordingly.*/
  while ( i < length ) {     struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];     if ( event->len ) {
      if ( event->mask & IN_CREATE ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          printf( "New directory %s created.1\n", event->name );
      fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , fd );
        }
        else {
          printf( "New file %s created.\n2", event->name );
      fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , fd );
        }
      }
      else if ( event->mask & IN_DELETE ) {
        if ( event->mask & IN_ISDIR ) {
          fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , fd );
          printf( "Directory %s deleted.\n", event->name );
        }
        else {
          printf( "File %s deleted.\n", event->name );
        }
      }
    }
    i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
  }
  /*removing the “/tmp” directory from the watch list.*/
   inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd );
   fclose(fd);
  /*closing the INOTIFY instance*/
   close( fd );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it simply blocks on the `read` call. From the comment above it:

> Actually this read blocks until the change event occurs

There simply isn't happening any of the events you're waiting for, and this `read` call will block until there is.

I suggest you run this program in one terminal, and in another do e.g.

```
$ touch /tmp/foo
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But no change even after this!

Comment: @user2134703 I suggest you run the program in a debugger, and step it through line by line. Then you will be able to see what happens, check values of variables, etc.

Comment: Oh sorry, It worked. It shows file created or deleted in terminal. But for single operation only. What should be done to listen multiple operations? running like nohup ./a & will work?

Comment: I am running through linux terminal, is it possible to run in debug mode in it or I have to use something else?

Comment: @user2134703 To do it continuously simply do the whole "read and check events" in a loop. So put an outer loop around the `read` and current loop.

Comment: @user2134703 If you compile with debug information (`-g` flag to GCC) then you can use [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) in the terminal, or one of the GUI frontends that exists for GDB.